# rewriting $A^2 + B^2 + C^2$ as $EF + FE+ GH + HG $

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, noncommutative-algebra

Here $A$, $B$, $C$ are arbitrary $n\times n $ matrices. I can find a solution as

$$A^2 + B^2 + C^2 = ((A+ iB )(A-iB) + (A-i B) (A+iB))/2 + C^2 ,$$

and identify $E = (A+ iB)/\sqrt{2}$, $F =( A- iB)/\sqrt{2}$, and $G=H = C/\sqrt{2}$.

Is it possible to avoid the imaginary unit $i$? That is, is there a solution such that $E,F,G,H$ are real combinations of $A,B,C$?

ps. The original problem is actually the following. I have a $3\times 3 $ complex symmetric matrix $M$. By the Autonne–Takagi factorization, it can be written as

$$M = u u^T + v v^T + w w^T ,$$

where $u,v,w$ are three column vectors. I want to rewrite $M $ as

$$ M = (e f^T+ f e^T ) + (g h^T + h g^T ), $$

with four column vectors $e, f, g, h$. Or in other words, I have a symmetric function $M(x_1, x_2)$, with $ x_i = 1, 2, 3$. I want to find functions $e(x), f(x), g(x),h(x)$ such that

$$M (x_1, x_2) = f(x_1)g(x_2) + g(x_1) f(x_2) + g(x_1)h(x_2) + h(x_1) g(x_2).  $$

The idea is actually that, taking two points on the manifold of the functions $\{ f(x_1)g(x_2) + g(x_1) f(x_2) \}$, we can span the whole space of symmetric matrices.

Comment: Could you say something about the origin of this problem ?

Comment: There are **real** matrices with the same property as imaginary unit (that is, being the square root of the minus unit matrix). Your solution, though, doesn't work in general; it relies on the premise that $A\cdot iB-iB\cdot A=0$.

Comment: Take the case of $2 \times 2$ matrices, your issue relies on solving a system of 4 equations in 16 variables. The probability that in $\mathbb R^{16}$, 4 hypersurfaces have a common point is very very low.

Comment: I have to take my second statement back. Your solution does **not** rely on $AB=BA$, because everything cancels out nicely without that premise. My first statement still stands: the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ is an example. Pity you can't simply take it instead of $i$, because then you'll need it to commute with $B$, which it might or might not do.

Comment: @JeanMarie  I have modified the problem.

Comment: Thanks for these precisions. Besides, is $M$ "symmetric complex" $M^T=M$ or "symmetric conjugated complex" $M^T=\overline{M}$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie  Just symmetric, not hermitian.

Answer (score 1):

I'll address the problem stated at the beginning of your question rather than your original problem.

Suppose there exists an algebraic identity
\begin{align}
A^2+B^2+C^2
&=(x_1A+y_1B+z_1C)(x_2A+y_2B+z_2C)\\
&+(x_2A+y_2B+z_2C)(x_1A+y_1B+z_1C)\\
&+(x_3A+y_3B+z_3C)(x_4A+y_4B+z_4C)\\
&+(x_4A+y_4B+z_4C)(x_3A+y_3B+z_3C)\tag{1}
\end{align}
where the $x_i$s, $y_i$s and $z_i$s are constant real numbers that does not depend on $A,B$ and $C$. When the matrices are $3\times3$ or larger, since there exist $A,B,C$ such that
$$
AB\ne0=A^2=B^2=C^2=BA=AC=CA=BC=CB,
$$
the coefficients of $AB$ on both sides of $(1)$ must be equal. Similarly, as there exist $A,B,C$ such that
$$
A^2\ne0=B^2=C^2=AB=BA=AC=CA=BC=CB,
$$
the coefficients of $AB$ on both sides of $(1)$ must be equal. It follows that, by permuting the roles of $A,B$ and $C$, we can compare coefficients of each of $A^2,B^2,C^2,AB,BA,AC,CA,BC$ or $CB$ on both sides of $(1)$. The problem thus reduces to solving the system of equations
\begin{cases}
2(x_1x_2+x_3x_4)=1,\\
2(y_1y_2+y_3y_4)=1,\\
2(z_1z_2+z_3z_4)=1,\\
x_1y_2+x_2y_1+x_3y_4+x_4y_3=0,\\
x_1z_2+x_2z_1+x_3z_4+x_4z_3=0,\\
y_1z_2+y_2z_1+y_3z_4+y_4z_3=0.
\end{cases}
(Since $AB$ and $BA$ have the same coefficients and similarly for other pairs of cross terms, there are only six equations in total.) You may try to solve this using a computer algebra system.